# Repeated call of WriteConsole (NASM x64 on Win64)

Tags: winapi, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

I started to learn Assembly lately and for practice, I thought of makeing a small game.
To make the border graphic of the game I need to print a block character n times.
To test this, I wrote the following code:

```
bits 64

global main
extern ExitProcess
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteConsoleA

section .text
    
main:
    mov rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle   
    mov rbx, rax
drawFrame:
    mov r12, [sze]
    l:
    mov rcx, rbx
    mov rdx, msg
    mov r8, 1
    sub rsp, 48
    mov r9, [rsp+40]
    mov qword [rsp+32], 0
    call WriteConsoleA
    dec r12
    jnz l
    
    xor rcx, rcx
    call ExitProcess

section .data
    score dd 0
    sze dq 20
    msg db 0xdb
```

I wanted to make this with the WinAPI Function for ouput.
Interestingly, this code stops after printing one char when using WriteConsoleA, but when I use C's putchar, it works correctly. I could also manage to make a C equivalent with the WriteConsoleA function, which also works fine. The disassembly of the C code didn't bring me further.

I suspect there's something wrong in my use of the stack that I don't see. Hopefully someone can explain or point out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to keep subtracting 48 from *RSP* through each loop. You only need to allocate that space once before the loop and before you call a C library function or the WinAPI.

The primary problem is with your 4th parameter in *R9*. The `WriteConsole` function is defined as:

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI WriteConsole(
>   _In_             HANDLE  hConsoleOutput,
>   _In_       const VOID    *lpBuffer,
>   _In_             DWORD   nNumberOfCharsToWrite,
>   _Out_opt_        LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten,
>   _Reserved_       LPVOID  lpReserved
> );
> ```

*R9* is supposed to be a pointer to a memory location that returns a `DWORD` with the number of characters written, but you do:

```
mov r9, [rsp+40]
```

This moves the 8 bytes starting at memory address `RSP+40` to *R9*. What you want is the address of `[rsp+40]` which can be done using the [`LEA`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lea) instruction:

```
lea r9, [rsp+40]
```

Your code could have looked like:

```
bits 64

global main
extern ExitProcess
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteConsoleA

section .text
    
main:
    sub rsp, 56          ; Allocate space for local variable(s)
                         ; Allocate 32 bytes of space for shadow store
                         ; Maintain 16 byte stack alignment for WinAPI/C library calls
                         ; 56+8=64 . 64 is evenly divisible by 16.
    mov rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle   
    mov rbx, rax
drawFrame:
    mov r12, [sze]
l:
    mov rcx, rbx
    mov rdx, msg
    mov r8, 1
    lea r9, [rsp+40]
    mov qword [rsp+32], 0
    call WriteConsoleA
    dec r12
    jnz l
    
    xor rcx, rcx
    call ExitProcess

section .data
    score dd 0
    sze dq 20
    msg db 0xdb
```

**Important Note**: In order to be compliant with the [64-bit Microsoft ABI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019) you must maintain the 16 byte alignment of the stack pointer prior to calling a WinAPI or *C* library function. Upon calling the `main` function the stack pointer (*RSP*) was 16 byte aligned. At the point the `main` function starts executing the stack is misaligned by 8 because the 8 byte return address was pushed on the stack. 48+8=56 doesn't get you back on a 16 byte aligned stack address (56 is not evenly divisible by 16) but 56+8=64 does. 64 is evenly divisible by 16.

Comment: Thank you alot! I somehow thought that the function will pop the shadow space and the allocated stack space after returning, thus moving the stack pointer 48 bytes forward. Also the WinAPI docs are very vague about the shadow space. :)